# Creating List of MonoBehaviours on an object

Tags: list, unity-game-engine

I have an object in the scene that has a monobehaviour attached. This monobehaviour has a public List. I want to be able to drag other monobheaviours from the project window to the inspector to fill this list so that this object can then add these monobehaviours to itself in the future to change its actions. The list shows up, but I cannot drag and drop them from the project window to the inspector - why is this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you should do something like this:

```
List<NameOfTheMonobehaviourScript> list = new List<NameOfTheMonobehaviourScript>();
```

And after that just drag the gameobjects with the scripts to the list, Unity will automatically reference the script on the gameobject instead of the gameobject itself.

Hope that this is what you meant!